# merge recursive on inner arrays of multidimensional array php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, merge

I have a multidimensional array that looks like such:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [email] => email1@gmail.com
        [added] => style-narcotics
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [email] => email1@gmail.com
        [added] => style-edm
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [email] => email2@gmail.com
        [added] => style-codeine
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [email] => email2@gmail.com
        [added] => style-food
    )
  )
```

I want to merge all the inner arrays combining the "added" key like such:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [email] => email1@gmail.com
        [added] => array(
                        [0]=>style-narcotics
                        [1]=>style-edm
                        )
    )



[1] => Array
    (
        [email] => email2@gmail.com
        [added] => array(
                        [0]=>style-codeine
                        [1]=>style-food
    )

  )
```

I have tried merge array recursive in different forms and call_user_func but it doesnt cut it. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: You want to change the type of `added` from `string` to `array` (add another nesting level) but [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) doesn't do that. It doesn't change the structure of the arrays it receives as arguments. It just combines them. You have to iterate over the input array and create the desired output.

Comment: good idea. that makes more sense. I fixed that part. I may be able to figure something out. I will post an update if I figure it out. Thanks @axiac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call it "grouping", but not "merging".
Use the following approach with `array_walk` and `array_values` functions:

```
$grouped = [];
// $arr is your initial array
array_walk($arr, function($v) use (&$grouped){
    if (array_key_exists($v["email"], $grouped)) {
        $grouped[$v["email"]]["added"][] = $v["added"];
    } else {
        $v["added"] = [$v["added"]];
        $grouped[$v["email"]] = $v;
    }
});

print_r(array_values($grouped));
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => email1@gmail.com
            [added] => Array
                (
                    [0] => style-narcotics
                    [1] => style-edm
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => email2@gmail.com
            [added] => Array
                (
                    [0] => style-codeine
                    [1] => style-food
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that uses [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$output = array_reduce(
    $input,
    function (array $carry, array $item) {
        $email = $item['email'];
        if (! isset($carry[$email])) {
            // It's a new email, make room for it in the output
            $carry[$email] = array('email' => $email, 'added' => array(), );
        }
        // Add the value of $item['added'] into the existing array
        $carry[$email]['added'][] = $item['added'];
        return $carry;
    },
    array()
);

// Output is indexed by email addresses. If you need numeric keys then...
$output = array_values($output);
```

The same logic as above but with an explicit iteration over the input array (the code is a couple of lines shorter):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($input as $item) {
    $email = $item['email'];
    if (! isset($carry[$email])) {
        // It's a new email, make room for it in the output
        $carry[$email] = array('email' => $email, 'added' => array(), );
    }
    // Add the value of $item['added'] into the existing array
    $carry[$email]['added'][] = $item['added'];
}
$output = array_values($output);
```